# CSS Vertical Button with vertical text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need vertical button with written vertical text inside. It should not be turned to 90 degree. I need to add some hover effect to right side if mouse on it and give white space between words. I have tried `white-space` and `word-space` but it did not help.

Example:

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" style="width:60px; height:600px; text-align:center;"><div style="width: 1ch; text-align:center; font: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;font-size:14pt; word-wrap: break-word;white-spacing: 3 px;">Online Sürücü Sifariş Et</div></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The button is a vertical button and the text is all one letter below the next. I have used `<br>` tags for every new line. Have a look

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" style="width:60px; height:600px; text-align:center;"><div style="width: 1ch; text-align:center; font: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;font-size:14pt; word-wrap: break-word;white-spacing: 3 px;">O<br>n<br>l<br>i<br>n<br>e<br><br>S<br>ü<br>r<br>ü<br>c<br>ü<br><br>S<br>i<br>f<br>a<br>r<br>i<br>ş<br><br>E<br>t<br></div></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `transform:rotate(-90deg);`

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" style=" text-align:center;">Online Sürücü Sifariş Et</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I wrote that i do not need transform:rotate(-90deg);

Comment: @Orik3ll0 Oh, Sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
.button {
   -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are [several ways](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css--net-15284) to accomplish what you're doing, but I like this one:

https://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/ybzway

It's a weird CSS attribute, but the imporant code is: `white-space: pre-line;`

Edit: there's also [`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation), but that's not supported by many browsers.

Edit: updated the CodePen html